# react native maps doenst exist airmap or MapsPackage type error

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

i have problem in react-native-maps .... pls help me

when i add "MapsPackage()" in mainapplication.java ; 
    React Native: error: constructor MapsPackage in class MapsPackage cannot be 
    applied to given types

when i delete "MapsPackage()" in mainapplication.java ; 
 doesnt work maps and i got error "airmap doenst not exist"

my build gradle ;

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
compile 'com.airbnb.android:react-native-maps:0.6.0'
//compile project(':react-native-maps-lib')
}
```

my mainapplication.java;

```
package com.polipoolapp;
import android.app.Application;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication 
{
 private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) 
{
   @Override
   public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
     return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
   }
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MapsPackage(),
      new MainReactPackage()
  );
}

@Override
protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
  return "index";
}
};

@Override
public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
 return mReactNativeHost;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
}
 }
```

my mainactivity.java;

```
package com.polipoolapp;   //<- put your app name
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  protected String getMainComponentName() {
return "PolipoolApp"; //<- put your app name
  }

  protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
  }


  }
```

Comment: No one to help                     ?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "firebase": "^4.7.0",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "*",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-drawer-menu": "^0.2.5",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.21.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.27",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"